# I have some employee data on my selection screen when i click on first name on employee data i need a popup display of emp details in abap

Tags: abap

I have a code written to display employee details in abap. at output when I click on first name at my selection screen I need all details of that employee as popup message. Can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a subscreen on selection screen and embed a oops alv with list of employees. You can then enabled Hotspot on entire record of alv and then display the pop-up in the corresponding hotspot event handler.